# How can I set up the fastest network for a Tor relay?

Tags: relays, tor-cloud, speed

Say I set up a server in the cloud as a relay, how can I set it up so I get maximum speed out of the network?  And how fast can a Tor-relay get with optimal bandwidth/response time?

Comment: Could you please clarify what it is you're really asking?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Good answer for Tor relay, so put up a question for Tor client here: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/how-can-i-optimize-the-connection-bandwidth-and-response-time-for-tor-browsing  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of today, the highest performing Tor node is pushing about 30 MB/s so if you are looking for tips, I'd suggest trying to match what the [fastest Tor nodes](http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/index.php?SR=Bandwidth&SO=Desc) are doing.

Firstly, choose a good platform. Linux works well, as does FreeBSD. Avoid Windows; while it is possible to get good performance out of Windows it requires a very different programming style to that of Unix and [Tor hasn't been optimised for that style](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/WindowsBufferProblems).

Of course you will need to turn off any arbitrary limits, such as the `BandwidthRate` Tor configuration option, but also the system limits (such as the maximum number of file descriptors, by calling `ulimit -n`, as performed by the [Debian launch script](https://gitweb.torproject.org/debian/tor.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/debian/tor.init)).

And have a powerful computer – your CPU needs to be able to keep up with your network and Tor requires several cryptographic operations for each cell that gets put on the network.

Most importantly, get a good network connection. Most Tor nodes are limited by their Internet connection's bandwidth so a reasonably low-latency high bandwidth link to a lot of Tor nodes will be necessary to get the best out of your node. Tor needs mostly the same upload and download bandwidth so a symmetric connection is best.

Once you've done all of these, keep an eye on the network and CPU usage and check for bottlenecks. [ARM](https://www.torproject.org/projects/arm.html.en) is a useful tool for monitoring a server. Do remember that it will take a long time ([maybe a couple of months](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay)) for your node to pick up enough users for it to reach capacity.